# NSMutableArray Shared Instance always return just last object

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, nsmutablearray, nsobject

i'm confusing about NSMutablearray addobject, i try to make  shared instance nsmutable array like this:

1.Shared instance

```
+ (netra*)someInstance
{
    if (sharedObject == nil) {
        sharedObject = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }
    return sharedObject;
}
```

1.1 Method to insert

```
+(void) setStock:(NSInteger *)stock{
    // Ensure we are using the shared instance
    netra *shared = [netra sharedInstance];
    [shared.stockInits addObject:stock];

}
```

1.3 Method to call nsmutablearray

```
+(NSMutableArray *) getStock{
    // Ensure we are using the shared instance
    netra *shared = [netra sharedInstance];
     return shared.stockInits ;
}
```

2.Method to insert

```
-(void) some{
for(int x=0;x<=1000;x++){
    [netra setStock:i];
 }
}
```

3. Method to call from other controller

```
for (int x=0; x<=[netra getStock].count;x++){
nslog (@"i-------->%d",x);
}
```

the log should be show 0-1000 right??? but why its always return 1000......1000 ? is that any wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'll make a getInstance methods like:

```
@implementation SinglentonObject{
    NSMutableArray *array;
}

+ (id)getInstance {
    static SinglentonObject *instance = nil;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (instance == nil) {
            instance = [[SinglentonObject alloc] init];
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

-(void) setStock:(NSNumber *)stock{
    // Ensure we are using the shared instance
    if(!array){
        array = [@[] mutableCopy];
    }
    [array addObject:stock];

}

- (NSMutableArray *) getStockArray
{
    return stockArray;
}
```

And in someMethod you have to change i by x:

```
-(void) write
{
    for(int x=0;x<=1000;x++){
       [[SinglentonObject getInstance] setStock:@x];
    }
}
```

For read this:

```
- (void) read
{
    for (NSNumber *currentStock in [[SinglentonObject getInstance] getStockArray]) {
        NSLog(@"%d", [currentStock intValue]);
    }
}
```

Remember to modify every method of getInstance as class methods.I recommend you that you read some Singlenton pattern article like http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/.

Comment: hmmm great answer, but why i can't iterate nsmutablearray from other class.. which if i count it,, it return correct length.. then it already inserted to nsmutablearray right? but why just  the last record showing? is that nsmutable array resetting the content while i call setStock?? or any other reason?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure about what piece of code provoke that weird behaviour because there are some candidates. I'm going to edit the answer to improve it.

Comment: hmm thanks! but it still give big mystery for me ;) and what if that data is not nsnumber? what if the data is nsdictionary that i want draw it into tableview?